# CSS selector extension for Firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, firebug

I am working on asp.net page and It has css applied to different controls. I want to access the controls in gridview and apply design to it. I have firebug installed but I dont know how can I know what selector to use for a particular control. Is there any option in firebug using which i can click the control and it tells me how to access this control ( different selectors for once control) like

```
.gridview thead th

or

.gridview img
```

How to to it in chrome developer tools? Is there any Firebug/chrome extension available for this?

Please suggest.

Comment: Chrome has a debugger plugin. Just right click > inspect element

Comment: yes but it doesnt show what is selector for currently selected element

Comment: It does on the bottom of your developertools, in the tabs, the blue one is the element you select, the ones before that are the parents, you can easily create a selector from this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a rather vague question because there are many CSS selectors that match a given element; some of them also match other similar elements...

That said, one way of getting a selector from an element in Firebug is to right-click it and pick "Copy CSS Path", and another is to copy the autofilled value given by "Add Rule..." in the Style side panel.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on that particular element you want to edit and then click on "Inspect Element", it will show HTML of that element selected at left bottom of chrome firebug and in left it will show `element.style {}` where you can style that element by putting your styles inside curly brackets. and you can also find the that class working for same element in left selected part.